# Laravel - access config inside protected array

Tags: php, laravel

Why can't I do this:

```
protected $attributes = array('name' => config('app.name'));
```

I get the following error:

> Constant expression contains invalid operations

EDIT: I should mention that the issue occurs when I do this in an Eloquent Model. If I do the following it works fine:

```
protected $attributes = array('name' => 'my app');
```

Comment: Is this the line the error is generated? And what is the result of `config('app.name')`?

Comment: Have edited to hopefully answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes property in Eloquent is (if I recall correctly) static (or Eloquent itself is static) and you only use constants to fill a static property (or a method).

If you add a construct to your class (in which you also call the parent construct) you can alter the attributes:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->attributes = array('name' => config('app.name'));
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

But don't forget that Laravel itself uses the attributes property, so you should probably use another name or add it to the array instead of setting it!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way instead:(I hope it helps)

In your model:

```
private $attributes;
```

In a function in your model:

```
public function anyfunction()
    {
       $this->attributes =  array('name' => config('app.name'));

        dd($this->attributes);
    }
```